# Points close to a geodetic line in spherical coordinates using Python

Tags: python, geospatial, haversine, spherical-coordinate

I am working with spherical coordinates (lon/lat, haversine metric) and am trying to find an efficient way to find all points that are both close to a geodetic line and their projection w.r.t the line is on the line. I have seen several libraries which can do spatial indexing or perform actions on geometries such as calculating intersection and whether a geometry contains another geometry but I did not find a library which can do spatial indexing and actions on geometry in spherical coordinates. Therefore, I tried something by myself. Using scikit-learn's BallTree for spatial indexing and querying of points with the haversine metric, I did the following:

- Inputs: points, line_point1, line_point2, distance_threshold
- Perform spatial indexing on points
- find points on line in intervals of at most distance_threshold by SLERPing between line_point1 and line_point2
- for each interpolated point including line_point1 and line_point2 do a radius query of sqrt(2)*distance_threshold (in order to promise no false negatives). Remove duplicates and obtain result in query_points
- remove all points in query_points that are either farther than distance_threshold from the line or their projection w.r.t the line is not on the line. Can be done by simple closed-form solutions.

I would like to know if there exists a more efficient and simple solution that does not require re-inventing the wheel.

I tested my implementation on 10000 coordinates uniformly distributed around the equator between both lon/lat -1 to 1. I attached an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvCXK.png) of the output I received. In cyan is the line itself, in blue are points close to the line and in orange-brown are the points which are not close to the line.

Comment: Seeking recommendations for software libraries is explicitly off-topic here, as you may recall from your study of the material in the help centre.  Had you asked how to perfect your own implementation of the code to make the calculations you need to make, well that would be a different, and most likely on-topic question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, High Performance Mark. I edited my post to hopefully fit an on-topic question.